# hadoop DFS start command not working and giving error

Tags: hadoop

hi i have configured hadoop and start the dfs by the following command `start_local_hdp_services`

but im getting the following error

**UPdated**

[image]

Im using hadoop on windows . installed using "msi"

Kindly help me

**Updated**

Im getting error in **Starting master, starting regionserver**

Answer (score 1):

nohup is a posix command, thus you either need to install [cygwin](http://cygwin.com) or run some sort of different script (.cmd or .bat file?)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup

I would lean toward install cygwin or similar, basically you need to be able to emulate linux commands. Any reason you aren't running hadoop on a linux vm? it would probably be your best bet IMO, hadoop was really meant to run on *nix. I doubt this will be the last problem you run into.

Comment: Hortonworks have contributed patches to the hadoop code so that it runs on windows. IIRC the issues were mainly password-less ssh and filesystem permissions. http://hortonworks.com/products/hdp-windows/

Comment: It was the filesystem stuff i was speaking to really, i guess i just cant imagine a bunch of windows nodes processing m/r jobs lol, im sure it can be done, but if you're just learning, i would recommend throwing up a unix vm to rid myself of compatibility problems (take out a variable)

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are running the Hortonworks distribution for windows

http://hortonworks.com/products/hdp-windows/

in which case shouldn't you be using the `start_local_hdp_services.cmd` command to start the services?

Comment: i have given this comment . and then i have the start dfs.sh

Comment: Well, I have skimmed through the installation docs http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP1/HDP-Win-1.1/bk_installing_hdp_for_windows/bk_installing_hdp_for_windows-20130225.pdf and don't see that command anywhere. Like Ryan says, *.sh and nohup are linux commands.

Comment: That won't work :) Use the hortonworks distribution if you are on windows or download an image from e.g. cloudera where everything is already installed in a linux environment.

Comment: Okay i have installed and started the service now i need to test it . How can i start doing it